# How do you remove the overlap of two mirrored, hollow, conical, cylinders?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How do I remove the overlapping middle sections of these two merged cones? I need to remove the part of these two cones that makes it look like a Venn diagram; so that the two cones are one shape with one large opening and two small openings.

I'm trying to represent binocular vision, if that helps you understand.

Here are a couple screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Create a bottomless cone object centered around the midpoint between the two cones.

In *Edit Mode* move all the geometry to one side the required distance so the cone is centered on the eye.

Now add a *Mirror Modifier* to the cone and turn off clipping. Activate bisecting for the X axis (or whatever orientation fits your particular model) and it will cut the cones at the bisecting plane.

[image]

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to use comments to say thanks. But thank you, I really appreciate the help.