# How to cut these two objects where they meet?

Tags: objects, faces

How can I remove the material where these two object meet? I'd like to keep the objects separate, but I imagine a vertical line right down the middle of these two objects.

[image: Blender Question]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184019

Comment: That looks easy enough. I've removed the right object, but when I mirror, I don't see a second object.

Comment: The bisect tool might work for this. Its a bit fiddly, though.

Comment: actually, with 2.90 alpha you can edit two separate objects at the same time. pretty cool...

Comment: @wilks You can edit separate objects at the same time in 2.83.4 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Empty (plane axes). This will be the mirror line.

Delete one of those "bars".

Select the other one and add a mirror modifier, and set the mirror object to the Empty.

Position the empty so that the bars are where you want them to be.

Go into edit mode and reshape the end of the bar by selecting verts and moving them. Get it to the look you want.

To turn both back into separate objects again apply the mirror modifier, go back into edit mode. Select everything with A, and press P and choose "Seperate **By Loose Parts**".

Comment: I attempted this, however, after the mirror modifier, when I rotate the object it doesn't rotate as I expect. It will rotate so the objects are lined up on whichever axis.

Comment: So after a little break, I decided to come back to this. This is the correct answer! Thanks for your help @Eric